# Using itertools to index an array

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Here is a section of code which is giving me a different answer to what I would expect. The line: `print list(x)` does what I expect. I would expect the line: `print random_array[list(x)]` to return the value of that element in the array but it returns three arrays. If for example `list(x)` returns `[9, 8, 7]` then `random_array[9, :, :], random_array[8, :, :], random_array[7, :, :]` will be printed. Can someone please explain to me why this is? And how I can get the expected answer?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

random_array = np.random.randint(0, 9, (10, 10, 10))
my_iterator = itertools.product(range(10),range(10),range(10))

for x in my_iterator:
    print list(x)
    print random_array[list(x)]
```

Comment: I have closed my answer. Numpy does support `random_array[(2,3,3)]`

Comment: It supports it but doesnt do what OP expects.

Comment: Reopened my answer; figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in a list rather than a tuple:

```
# What you are doing
random_array[[2, 3, 3]]  # semantics: [arr[2], arr[3], arr[3]]

# What you want to be doing
random_array[(2, 3, 3)]  # semantics: arr[2][3][3], same as arr[2,3,3]
```

In short: do not cast your tuples to lists using `list(...)`.

Comment: I see that I am passing in a list rather than I slice. So:  `random_array[[2, 3, 3]]`

Comment: Can you expand the tuple like: `random_array[*(2, 3, 3)]`

Comment: @Marcin: that's exactly what I was in the process of testing

Comment: I believe this answer explains more than the chosen answer.

Comment: @ninjagecko I guess I will wait a bit before I except an answer. But most of them have been very helpful for me to learn about itertools and indexing. So thank you.

Comment: @NicholasPringle: I removed my answer, feel free to accept ninja. Let's give the points to whoever ask for them!

Comment: Here are some docs if anyone wants to know more about numpy indexing. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
print random_array[x[0], x[1], x[2]]
```

If you pass a list as index to numpy it will iterate trough the index list and get you that slice of elements. For example:

```
>>> test = numpy.array(range(10))
>>> idx = [1, 2, 3]
>>> test[idx]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
print random_array[x]
```

When you pass a list, [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) is taking place, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I would expect the line: print random_array[list[x]) to return the
>   value of that element in the array

But your code does not contain such a line. I expect this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Stop being such a pendant. Clearly he's referring to the last line of his extract.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. I meant "I would expect the line: print random_array[list(x)]" and I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidKemp: Tell that to your python interpreter.

Comment: Marcin has a point I guess. Precision is important in all aspects.